# Windows Live popup window

Tags: javascript, windows-live

When I use code like this at the start of a web page

```
    WL.init({
      client_id: "0000000040102460",
      redirect_uri: document.URL,
      scope: "wl.signin",
      response_type: "token"
    });
    WL.login().then(
      function (response) {
        WL.api({ path: "me", method: "GET" })
          .then(function (response) {
            userid = response.id;
            $("#wlProfileName").text(response.name);
            init(response);
          });
      });
```

the login process occurs in a pop-up window. This is a bad idea, not least because many browsers are configured to prohibit them.

When you log in to eg outlook.com the process occurs in the same browser window. How do I go about achieving that?

---

The upvoting of the question combined with the utter lack of answers is quite alarming. However, I do have an idea: WL.debug.js is available for examination. It may be possible to hack this to use an IFRAME instead of a popup.

This should solve the problem without changing the basic method and flow of the WL code.

Right now I'm about to depart for a few weeks of vacation and I won't have facilities to pursue this thought, but if anyone cares to have a crack at the above modification, I'd love to join in when I return.

Answer (score 0):

Try this php sample. Go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7843, click on download button, choose just **webauth-php-1.2.tar.gz** and download.. Then after unzipping put content into `xampp/htdocs` on your pc and call address `http://localhost/webauth/sample/index.php` from your browser.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, but it may be a while before I do, other fish to fry at the moment :)